# DHCP on a lan-connected wireless access point: why does it work?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, lan, dhcp

I'm trying to extend my home network by cascading wireless routers following this topology:

`Internet (WAN) <-(dsl cable)-> Technicolor wlan router <-(ethernet)-> TP-Link access point`.

Both the technicolor and the tp-link router have wlan capabilities, and I want to get internet access for devices connected to either of them.

I followed the general recommendation for my case, i.e.

1. set up tp-link in access point mode
2. connect the two routers with an ethernet cable
3. give TP-Link a static private ip in the lan (from Technicolor's settings)
4. set Technicolor's dhcp to assign addresses different than the one used to access TP-Link's settings
5. disable TP-Link's DHCP

This worked yesterday but today it stopped working. Started working again after turning TP-Link off and back on. I updated TP-Link's firmware, suspecting it was a software defect.

After the update, wireless devices trying to connect to TP-Link couldn't seem to obtain an ip address as if they couldn't be reached by Technicolor's DHCP server.

I tried activating DHCP on TP-Link and now wireless devices connected to either device can reach the internet (so WAN access works as intended)

I think I managed to make two discrete local networks, both connected to the internet through Technicolor.
I'm very puzzled nonetheless. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the TP-Link is still in "access point" mode? Through which port is it connected to the Technicolor? If you used the TP-Link's "WAN" port for this, have you tried a LAN port instead? (After disabling its DHCP again, of course.)

Comment: I'm positive the settings have not changed (i checked). I'm currently using the wan port, and haven't tried a LAN one. is it supposed to work this way? Shouldn't "access point mode" be binded to wan port? For context I have 4 ports only, one of which is labeled WAN/LAN4

Comment: Fundamentally an "access point" is a bridge, the same kind of bridge that links the LAN ports together, or the Wi-Fi LAN to the Ethernet LAN. So your kind of router can work as an access point with no special options as soon as you connect it through one of its LAN ports (keeping the WAN port unused). The main reason why TP-Link has it as a special option is to turn the useless WAN port (routed) into an additional LAN port (bridged). But in case this option doesn't work, the remaining LAN ports are still always bridged to Wi-Fi and they're worth a try.

Comment: it worked this way, thanks! Please post your answer so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that either the firmware update broke the "access point" setting, or changed it halfway so that the web UI thinks it's enabled but the underlying system thinks it's disabled.

Either way, you can make it work without the setting **by using a LAN port instead**, because home routers are  *already* access points (among other things) and there's no difference in how the actual Wi-Fi works, only in how the WAN port works.

Access points are bridges with no IP routing, and practically every home wireless router already has its Wi-Fi and all its LAN ports bridged together into one network. All ports in a bridge are equal.

So the only important thing the setting does is disable IP routing for the WAN port, adding it to the bridge instead – basically giving you one extra LAN port. (That's why it is dual-labelled "WAN/LAN4".) But if you instead connect the TP-Link through one of its other LAN ports you will have practically the same effect anyway.